# How can I wait for background processes to finish in Bash script - wait not working

Tags: bash, process, background, wait

The aim is to run two workloads concurrently, so each workload needs to be started in the background.  Each of those workloads will have n workload processes running in the background (in the example below the 'workload' is a script that sleeps for n seconds).  I want to wait for all background processes to complete before additional processing, whereas script returns immediately.  As soon as I add the & to the {}, it stops waiting for the workload processes to complete

```
for wl_num in 1 2 ; do
  echo "... Workload $wl_num"
  {
    for i in `seq 1 3` ; do
      echo ...... workload process $i
      . run_sleep.sh 300 &
    done 
  } &
done
wait
echo ... done waiting for both workloads
```

I have also tried saving the pids and then waiting for them, but this also does not work, in that the script returns immediately, while the processes continue in the background.

```
for wl_num in 1 2 ; do
  echo "... Workload $wl_num"
  {
    for i in `seq 1 3` ; do
      echo ...... workload process $i
      . run_sleep.sh 5 &
      pids[${i}=$!  
    done 
  } & 
  wlpids[${db_num}]=$!
done
for pid in ${pids[*]} ; do
  wait $pid
done
for pid in ${wlpids[*]} ; do
  wait $pid
done
echo ... done waiting for both workloads
```

How can I wait for all backgrounds to be complete?

Comment: Apologies.. the script was formatted on my screen but lost formatting when the question was submitted!

Comment: If you're running the whole `do` body in the background, there's no need to put `run_sleep` in the background as well.

Comment: [formatting code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: `wait` can only wait for the shell's children. If you put the whole `{}` in the background, then that process is the child of the shell, while `run_sleep` is in a grandchild.

Comment: There are more commands in the { } that take time other than the sleep.  I want the two workloads to start at approximately the same time, but because of the other commands in the { }, there is a delay of a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the workload in the background, it forks a subshell. The main shell process can only wait for its own children, not the grandchildren.

Use another `wait` inside each workload process to have that subshell wait for its children, while the main shell waits for the workloads.

```
for wl_num in 1 2 ; do
  echo "... Workload $wl_num"
  {
    for i in `seq 1 3` ; do
      echo ...... workload $wl_num process $i
      . run_sleep.sh 300 &
    done 
    wait 
    echo "... Workload $wl_num done"
  } &
done
wait
echo ... done waiting for both workloads
```